# How do you fix "InputEventData must specify size in bytes!" in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just loaded my game from my Windows computer to my Mac to work on it through Plastic SCM. I am getting a single line error

`InputEventData must specify size in bytes!`

That is it. I am using Unity's new Input System and it obviously works on my Windows computer.

Any ideas?

[image]